# How to do truncated SVD in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svd

I have two matrices, `train` and `test`.  How do I "fit" a singular value decomposition on `train` and apply the fitted transformation to `test`?

For example

```
library(irlba)

# train
train <- cbind(matrix(runif(16, min=0, max=1), nrow=8), 
               matrix(runif(16, min=30, max=31), nrow=8))
train[1:4, ] = train[1:4, ] + 50

# test
test <- cbind(matrix(runif(16, min=0, max=1), nrow=8), 
              matrix(runif(16, min=30, max=31), nrow=8))
test[1:4, ] = test[1:4, ] + 50

# trunacted SVD applied to train
S <- irlba(t(train), nv=2)

> train
         [,1]    [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 50.39686 50.8733 80.57 80.51
[2,] 50.42719 50.2288 80.64 80.17
[3,] 50.87391 50.6059 80.19 80.61
[4,] 50.52439 50.7037 80.59 80.36
[5,]  0.43121  0.4681 30.93 30.76
[6,]  0.69381  0.5647 30.12 30.11
[7,]  0.02068  0.3382 30.37 30.04
[8,]  0.61101  0.5401 30.12 30.86

> S$v
       [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 0.4819  0.23134
[2,] 0.4805  0.18348
[3,] 0.4816  0.07372
[4,] 0.4816 -0.05819
[5,] 0.1370 -0.59769
[6,] 0.1342 -0.20746
[7,] 0.1335 -0.70946
[8,] 0.1358 -0.01972
```

Now, how do I reduce the dimensions of `test`?  (Also, please note that my *real* datasets are large and sparse.)

Comment: SVD isn't compressing the size of `train` or `test`, per se. It is a matrix factorization, into the column orthonormal matrices U and V and diagonal matrix D. which can reconstruct your matrix as `S$u%*%diag(S$v)%*%t(S$v)`. The "dimension reduction" comes from choosing to only use a certain number of singular values in the reconstruction, in your case 2. The difference being that the function `irlba` you use only calculates 2 singular values instead of calculating 4 and subsetting the first 2.

Comment: What you have above is not dissimilar to `S <- svd(train);
S$u[,1:2] %*% diag(S$d[1:2]) %*% t(S$v[,1:2])` where we explicitly throw out the last two singular values.